# How to fix this crash in facebook::react::Value::toJSONString

Tags: android, react-native, expo, segmentation-fault

### Problem

I'm getting an annoying crash report in production, which I can't solve but I think it's related to this [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22682).

The problem is that it looks like the crash is randomly appear, and not after a certain action.

I tracked down the [source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.57.8/ReactCommon/jschelpers/Value.cpp#L62) of the next line, which I think have to do something with the crash, but I'm not sure.

```
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 0005e669  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so (JSValueCreateJSONString+72)
```

**UPDATE:**
By using addr2line I managed to follow down the stack which looks like this:

[ReactCommon/jschelpers/Value.cpp#64](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.57.8/ReactCommon/jschelpers/Value.cpp#L64)

```
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 0005e669  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so (JSValueCreateJSONString+72)
```

[ReactCommon/cxxreact/MethodCall.cpp#21](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.57.8/ReactCommon/cxxreact/MethodCall.cpp#L21)

```
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 0003b3b9  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libreactnativejni.so (_ZNK8facebook5react5Value12toJSONStringEj+20)
```

[ReactCommon/cxxreact/Instance.cpp#69](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.57.8/ReactCommon/cxxreact/Instance.cpp#L69)

```
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 00033c3b  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libreactnativejni.so (_ZN8facebook5react11JSCExecutor19flushQueueImmediateEONS0_5ValueE+26)
```

[ReactCommon/cxxreact/Instance.cpp#125](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.57.8/ReactCommon/cxxreact/Instance.cpp#L125)

```
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 00033d6f  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libreactnativejni.so (_ZN8facebook5react11JSCExecutor25nativeFlushQueueImmediateEjPKPK13OpaqueJSValue+86)
```

**UPDATE:**
I've created a snack demo to reproduce the crash.
By storing this string each time `"012345678".repeat(1024*1024)`, you can reproduce the bug. *(For me it crashes when I add the third or fourth)*

[Snack demo](https://snack.expo.io/@fitsolutionskft/redux-offline-sandbox)

### Questions:

If you have any advice how could i get more info out of adb logcat or other software, when the crash happens, please let me know.

Also if you had similar error before, please let me know how did you solve it and what was the cause of the crash.

### Crash report:

```
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 003b3ac0  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 003b1601  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00364861  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0037134d  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 003706c1  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00370e55  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 00290f71  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 00291fbd  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 002913ab  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 002908d9  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 0029402f  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 0005e669  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so (JSValueCreateJSONString+72)
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 0003b3b9  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libreactnativejni.so (_ZNK8facebook5react5Value12toJSONStringEj+20)
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 00033c3b  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libreactnativejni.so (_ZN8facebook5react11JSCExecutor19flushQueueImmediateEONS0_5ValueE+26)
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 00033d6f  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libreactnativejni.so (_ZN8facebook5react11JSCExecutor25nativeFlushQueueImmediateEjPKPK13OpaqueJSValue+86)
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 00034ab1  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libreactnativejni.so
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 0004eda9  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 0012fa9b  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
2019-02-07 14:22:50.203 10137-10137/? A/DEBUG:     #18 pc 0012f60d  /data/app/com.xyzor.timer-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
2019-02-07 14:22:52.073 1257-10138/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.xyzor.timer/host.exp.exponent.experience.ShellAppActivity
2019-02-07 14:22:52.140 1257-1272/? D/ViewRootImpl@2042207[timer]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=true
2019-02-07 14:22:52.142 1257-1272/? D/WindowManager: openInputChannel mInputChannel: a585ad2 Application Error: com.xyzor.timer (server)
2019-02-07 14:22:52.144 1257-1272/? D/ViewRootImpl@2042207[timer]: setView = DecorView@83d521e[timer] touchMode=true
2019-02-07 14:22:52.162 7102-10144/? W/PkgUtils: p: com.xyzor.timer, u:0
2019-02-07 14:22:52.167 1257-1272/? D/ViewRootImpl@2042207[timer]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
2019-02-07 14:22:52.194 1257-1272/? D/ViewRootImpl@2042207[timer]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[256,816][1280,1279] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true 547307523072} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
2019-02-07 14:22:52.194 1257-1272/? D/ViewRootImpl@2042207[timer]: mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true 547307523072} hwInitialized=true
2019-02-07 14:22:52.197 1257-1272/? D/ViewRootImpl@2042207[timer]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
2019-02-07 14:22:52.197 1257-1272/? D/ViewRootImpl@2042207[timer]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true 547307523072}
2019-02-07 14:22:52.209 7187-7204/? W/PkgUtils: p: com.xyzor.timer, u:0
2019-02-07 14:22:52.230 1257-1272/? D/WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{a585ad2d0 u0 Application Error: com.xyzor.timer} mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
2019-02-07 14:22:52.231 1257-1272/? D/ViewRootImpl@2042207[timer]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(256, 816 - 1280, 1279) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
2019-02-07 14:22:52.236 1257-1272/? D/WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{a585ad2d0 u0 Application Error: com.xyzor.timer} mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN
2019-02-07 14:22:52.448 1257-1385/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{2a8ca6fd0 u0 com.xyzor.timer/host.exp.exponent.experience.ShellAppActivity}
2019-02-07 14:22:52.449 1257-1385/? D/WindowManager: disposeInputChannel mInputChannel: 2a8ca6f com.xyzor.timer/host.exp.exponent.experience.ShellAppActivity (server)
2019-02-07 14:22:52.449 1257-2210/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.xyzor.timer (pid 9982) has died(864,760)
```

### General info:

- I'm using Expo with Expo SDK 31 and react native 0.57.
- I'm able to log the app through adb logcat.
- I don't have much experience with native android development

Comment: Seems like a rendering problem (your window died) See ...If you are using react [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#state-reconciler), wrap your root component with [PersistGate](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/PersistGate.md). This delays the rendering of your app's UI until your persisted state has been retrieved and saved to redux.

Comment: @JonGoodwin Thanks, I'll look into it.

Could you tell me why do you think it's a rendering problem?

Comment: Unfortunately that was not the solution. I created a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@fitsolutionskft/redux-offline-sandbox) where I use redux-persist v5.

Comment: At least now I was able to create an example where it is easy to reproduce the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I was passing an object to the `JSON.stringify()` which was so big, that the app didn't have enough memory to store that string.

1. Solution (ideal)

Switching to a streaming method. Something like [JSONStream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream)

For me this wasn't a possibility because I'm using Expo (maybe not even in RN can be done)

2. Splitting the data to separate file

Since the source of the problem is that you can't pass too big object/string to JSON.[stringify, parse], I just simple split the data to different files.

Luckily I was using  [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) with custom store engine, so I was able to modify the necessary methods to handle these data.